# InvalidAlgorithmParameterException When Loading Encrypted Private Key With Bouncycastle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pem, dsa

I'm trying to read an encrypted DSA private key file with Bouncycastle using this code:

```
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    ...    

    public PrivateKey loadKey(String fileName, String password) {

        try (PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

            PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptedKeyInfo = (PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) pemParser.readObject();

            InputDecryptorProvider decryptorProvider = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder().build(password.toCharArray());
            PrivateKeyInfo keyInfo = encryptedKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(decryptorProvider);

            JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
            return converter.getPrivateKey(keyInfo);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But the method `encryptedKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo` fails with the following exception:

```
org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException: unable to read encrypted data: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.3 not available: requires PBE parameters
    at com.psc.bouncycastle@1.57.0//org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.my.app.MyClass.loadKey(MyClass.java:96)
    ... 182 more
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.3 not available: requires PBE parameters
    at com.psc.bouncycastle@1.57.0//org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder$1.get(Unknown Source)
    ... 184 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: requires PBE parameters
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.engineInit(PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.java:187)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:839)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:901)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1286)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1223)
    ... 185 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Parameters missing
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES1Core.init(PBES1Core.java:214)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.engineInit(PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.java:221)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.engineInit(PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.java:185)
    ... 189 more
```

The code seems to work on Java 8, but fails on Java 11. Any ideas?

Comment: Please recheck what you're running. I get this problem with _any_ version of Java but _only_ if the `addProvider` call is omitted (or reversed with `removeProvider`) and using Bouncy 1.53 up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I was using incorrect **Bouncy Castle Security Provider**:

```
Security.getProvider("BC"); //or Security.getProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
```

Returned a Bouncy Castle Security Provider that was registered by a JDBC driver (*jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider*) and was containing **2727 parameters**.

But when I removed existing, mentioned Provider and registered a new one, provided by **bcprov** library (*org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider*).
I got a Bouncy Castle Provider containing proper **2944** parameters and it started working without the error:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

Security.removeProvider("BC");
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

*To sum up*: Please compare your Bouncy Castle providers for both Java versions and make sure you're using a correct one.

Dependencies from my pom file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.70</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.70</version>
        </dependency>
```